# CSS doesn't apply for second entry, what's wrong in the lines here?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply background image (same one) to two div tags:

```
.abc { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -133px; width: 256px; height: 256px; };

.def { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -0px; width: 128px; height: 128px; };
```

HTML:

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf8"><link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'' media='all' /></head><body>
<div class="def">def</div>
<div class="abc">abc</div></body></html>
```

But only one got displayed, if I put .def definition before the one of .abc, .def got displayed and .abc got no background.

[image]

Comment: remove `;` at the end of the lines in css file.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think these type of question should be remove. These are very low level questions. What say? Look ppl are still answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't used  `;` after in your css

**replace** into

```
.abc { 
background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -133px; 
width: 256px;
height: 256px;
};

.def { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -0px; 
width: 128px;
height: 128px; };
```

**this**

```
     .abc { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -133px; 
width: 256px; 
height: 256px; }

        .def { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -0px; 
width: 128px; 
height: 128px; }
```

more info http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html

Answer (score 1):

I presume there shouldn't be a ';' after the curly braces

```
.abc { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -133px; width: 256px; height: 256px; }

.def { background: url('images/autogen.png') no-repeat 0px -0px; width: 128px; height: 128px; }
```